# python sqlite - where condition is empty

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlite, where-clause

I have a table in an sqlite database called 'General'. It has four columns 'One', 'Two' and three

One has a list of names:

```
One = ['James', 'Ben', 'John', 'Peter']
```

Two, a list of country's:

```
Two = ['Uk', 'USA', 'Germany', 'UK']
```

three, a score:

```
Three = [3,6,5,9]
```

In python I can access this easily enough using pd.read_sql_query and adding .format to get the relevant data.

```
name = 'John'
country = 'Germany'

conn = sqlite3.connect('score_history.db')
df = pd.read_sql_query('''SELECT * FROM General WHERE (name='{}') & (country='{}')'''.format(name, country), conn)
conn.close()
```

However, sometimes I just want to search the country (for instance UK) and leave name blank. How would I adapt the above so that the same code can be used to either just search by country / name / score, but also be able to search multiple columns as above for country and name, or country and score or name and score?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could explicitly handle the empty string in the comparisons, like so:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query('''
    SELECT * 
    FROM General 
    WHERE ('{}' = '' OR name='{}') AND ('{}' = '' OR country='{}')
    '''.format(name, name, country, country), conn)
```

You can also use `IN` to avoid repeating the parameter:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query('''
    SELECT * 
    FROM General 
    WHERE '{}' IN ('', name) AND '{}' IN ('', country)
    '''.format(name, country), conn)
```